# categories vs utility classes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Why are utility classes considered bad practice in iOS ? And categories used as a replacement instead of helper classes/utility classes. Is there any particular benefit that we get out of categories that we don't get from utility classes ?

Comment: who is considering them bad practice?

Comment: Categories and utility classes can be used in different situations. Sometimes you can use either and different people with different programming background will choose differently. There is nothing bad with utility classes if you keep them small and dedicated to specific tasks (not doing tens of different things).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Categories have a specific purpose.  They extend functionality of a class in code that's external to the class for some reason (you don't have source for the original, you want different visibility for the category, ...).

When you say "helper" class, that sounds like delegates rather than categories...or just simple composition.

Actual utility classes -- ones that have no instances or state -- do exist where needed.

Comment: by helper classes I meant utility classes

Answer (score 1):

Utilities are not a bad practice in iOS. Sometimes, it makes sense to have them around if you need a central hub for useful functions with a specific common goal (i.e.: a MathUtils class for parsing doubles or ints in objective-c).

Having said that, by convention categories / extensions are considered nicer as they allow you to operate directly on the objects themselves without the need to allocate memory / instantiate other objects. For example, you can create a category on an NSNumber object to divide by a number easily, allowing you to have a language syntax that is easy to follow: i.e:

in swift:

```
number.divideBy(2)
```

or in objective-c

```
[number divideBy:2]
```

As opposed to:

```
let utility = UtilityClass()
utility.divideNumber(number, by:2)
```

Hopefully this helps convince you to start working with Categories, they are your best friends here!

Comment: If you use class methods you don't need to initialise the class. You could do `[UtilityClass devideNumber:2];`

Comment: @JasperPol You can use class utilities, yes, but the example you provided won't work. I'm assuming you meant to write something like `[UtilityClass divideNumber:number by:2]`

Comment: correct. It was a just an example of quicker accessing the Utilities class instead of having to initialise it every time you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

One should not say that utility classes are worse at all. It depends on the task.

Maybe the reason for the statement is that developers coming from different programming languages don't know categories and simply use utility classes, even a category would do the job better. This esp. applies to utility classes, whose single purpose is to split an existing parent class into more lightweight parts. This is akin of bad, because it does not reflect the meaning of a class: If code is put into a class semantical correctly, you should not break the semantics for administrative reasons. It is a part of the class, let it be a part of the class.

There is a simple test for it: If you find yourself typing `self.master` (for `master` being the original class) very often (esp. this is the only usage of `self` at all) it is obvious that the utility class has no individual purpose and completely works on the original class.

But, of course, if you have a separate functionality, backed with a separate set of ivars, it might be correct to have extra classes for them. (Are they still utility classes? Maybe you should ask your Q more specific.)